# Selenium - Slider Handle

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried the code for slider handle in Selenium and run the program and I got this error message. So, Please anyone suggest me the solution for this error message
No signature of method:

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.clickAndHold() is applicable for argument types: (ManageActSpec$_spock_feature_2_2_closure3_closure4) values: [ManageActSpec$_spock_feature_2_2_closure3_closure4@1920887] Possible solutions: clickAndHold(), clickAndHold(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code/html.

Comment: Explain in detail with code like how slider is and what you want to do? I mean do you want to move slide by slide horizontally using selenium? OR something else?

Comment: Please include your code and the HTML